# Are reviewers more harsh or lenient at different times of the day?

Tags: support, review-queues, users

I tend to see that reviewers are more lenient at certain times of the day. For example, I see many (very) minor suggested edits approved at around 1pm UTC. Has your experience also seen this sort of thing occuring, and are there any statistics that show the ratio of positive to negative reviews?

Comment: Is that data available in SEDE maybe?

Comment: 1pm is about when the college kids wake up, and it's mostly them who badge-game.

Comment: 1PM UTC. That sounds like the time I'm usually not home.

Comment: Why are we limiting the discussion to reviewers? What about downvotes and general votes. or maybe you meant that. anyway nice question

Comment: Wouldn't this be something scary to accurately measure though? Nightime-india is daytime-USA. We'd have to split those groups I think. But intuitively, people ae crotchety at EOD - that much is clear. [Judges are lenient after lunch, for eg](https://www.google.com/search?q=judges+lenient+after+lunch&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)

Comment: @Adel: I was initially thinking of this in the context of reviews which is most obvious from what I see, though this could apply to any part of the system.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a statistic, it plots the ratio of questions vs answers throughout the day, broken down by UTC hour and annotated by locale:

[image]

It is a bit out of whack, horizontal axis is off by an hour, screwed up the title and Americas should be moved left by an hour.  I just got sick of fighting Excel.

Rough indication is that SO users tend to ask questions in the morning and start answering them in the afternoon.  1 PM stands out, that's when Europe has answered what they could and, perhaps, starts switching to optional activities like editing.  I can't completely prove it of course, sounds right however.

Take it for what is worth, not much.  Notable too is that this was collected from SEDE data that covered the entire life of SO.  The numbers are *much* worse today, that graph is off the chart below 1.50 for 2013.  If SO had to pass the Area-51 beta test today then it would probably be closed down :)

Comment: What query did you use use for that? It would be interesting to point it at different sites with variations such as 'when are questions asked', 'when are answers given' and 'when are things closed'?

Comment: Intriguing, thank you for sharing @HansPassant, although i second the request of how you queried this info.  Do you have to be an employee to get that kind of logistics?  Or just a senior editor?

Answer (score 3):

Mostly dealing with the C++ tag, I see a cyclic change in responsiveness on SO: During US office hours it seems more likely to get more and faster answers than outside of those. In fact, I sometimes did not bother to ask a question before it was afternoon here (Germany), because of this. I always considered this obviously related to the (assumed) fact that the majority of SO users are living in the US.

Around 1pm UTC is the morning on the US east coast. Likely that's when people arrive at the office and look at SO with the day's first coffee at hand, or when they sit down at home to look at a few questions/try to gain some rep before they go to work, or when they look at their tablet/phone while commuting.