# Does it matter what time of day I post?

Tags: discussion

Does it matter what time of day I post or do you guys have some sort of post circulation thing in place?

For instance if I post when everybody else is asleep, or during the weekend, will my post have dropped so far down the queue that nobody will find it by the time they get back?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251120/are-reviewers-more-harsh-or-lenient-at-different-times-of-the-day

Answer (score 11):

**Executive Summary:** Yes. Time does matter, but it matters far less than creating a good question. Don't hesitate to ask a good question just because of the time of day.

There are [definitely times with higher traffic than others](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/196632/submit-hour-of-questions-and-answers#graph) (all times in the graph are in GMT). Time matters most in high-traffic tags where there is a steady flow of traffic (see [top tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags)) since questions will push your answer off the top of the page. On smaller tags, this is less of an issue as many people browse all the questions submitted on that tag.

People generally post during the work day (9-5 on weekdays), and users are primarily located in the US, followed by Europe, then Asia ([more info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/198372/209637)). So if you post at this time (midnight East Coast US, 9pm West Coast US, 5am UK, etc.), then your question will likely get viewed primarily by Asian/Oceanian users, and then the European users as they trickle in.

To give your question the best shot, [read the help center on asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part on [including a code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure to create a useful title, and to tag your post appropriately. If your question is good, it will get noticed as it will get bumped any time someone gives an answer to it (and if the question is good, someone will likely give an answer to it because you've made it easy for them).

Comment: It looks like the frequency of questions and answers varies only by 10% over the day. Rather a minor issue.

Answer (score 5):

Only if you care about where, geographically, your answers come from.

If your posts drop down the queue, it is because of activity, not inactivity.  It is because people are present and using the site.